# How implement data structure which is map many to one?

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary, many-to-one

I want to have map in reverse direction which is mean I have lots of keys and only one value. I need this structure so when I search for one of the key I got the value.

[image]

I can use a simple Hash Map but it waste space because of storing value many times. I am looking for optimize and efficient implementation in java. I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: You will always *have* to keep a copy of at least a pointer to the value for each key. So I'd say a hash map is the perfect choice here.

Comment: Have you ever heard about The Fallacy of Premature Optimization?

Comment: what's `hat` actually? is it a class or a string? what about using inheritance and `instanof` operator? if you are so aware of space usage, why you are using java? you can still use `HashMap`, but make the value to be enum type.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr hat is just a string

Comment: @clapas No I never heard about it.

Comment: @user3487667 so as i said, you could use `HashMap` but with a enum type as cloth. if you name `cloth`, `toString` will return exactly `cloth`.

Comment: Making things enums isn't necessary at all here -- no matter what object you use, you'll be sharing references to the same object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HashMap should be used. when you put "cloth" into HashMap as a value, it is not duplicated in memory. just reference is written into HashMap.

```
String hat = "hat";
String dress = "dress";
String paths = "paths";
String scarf = "scarf";
String cloth = "cloth";
HashMap h = new HashMap();
h.put(hat,cloth);
h.put(paths,cloth);
h.put(dress,cloth);
h.put(scarf,cloth);
```

for this sample, memory keeps only cloth object for once.

Answer (score 1):

You don't waste space because each entry shares a reference to the same object. Please post some code if you want a more elaborated answer.